# How do you get the user defined "Device Name" in android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the user defined device name that is set in settings.  I've tried several options and so far nothing.

If it helps or hurts I am needing it in a BroadcastReceiver

Thanks

Answer (score 31):

This got me what I was needed... 
http://cmanios.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/bluetooth-adapter-device-name-and-mac-address-in-android/

```
BluetoothAdapter myDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    String deviceName = myDevice.getName();
```

Make sure you add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

to your manifest

Comment: You can accept your own answer.  As it would have been a stretch to guess that you were talking about Bluetooth from your question, I added a tag and mention to the title.

Comment: In the settings it says nothing about Blue tooth on either of the devices I was working with.  I went by trial and error until I found it.

Comment: Alright, I rolled back my edit.  But your solution reveals the problem to be one which has no general solution - on many devices what you are trying to do is simply not possible at all, as there's no means for the user to name the device.

Comment: please take note. as this answer works, you still have to restart your device if you update your device name on your device settings for you to get the updated name.

Comment: Since BT is mandatory to ship the phone with Google Apps, we can expect all devices except a few like Amazon Kindle to have BT.http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24464/any-android-phones-that-dont-support-bluetooth/48233#48233

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getName()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 16):

Following works for me

```
String deviceName = Settings.Global.getString(<Context>.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVICE_NAME);
```

Comment: Not working on huawei. I want to get user custom name of device

Comment: Requires API-Level 25 - but on devices with this level or higher, it seems to be the most reliable option

Comment: Does this require any permissions? Does the Play Store allow it?

Answer (score 15):

In summary, there is no single consistent way to retrieve the user-customized device name.

However, there are numerous utilities that you can use that will work on different models and manufacturers:

1. `Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), “bluetooth_name”);` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#getString%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String%29))
2. `Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), “bluetooth_name”);` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#getString%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String%29))
3. `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getName();` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getName%28%29))
4. `Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), “device_name”);` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#getString%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String%29))
5. `Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), “lock_screen_owner_info”);` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#getString%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String%29))

1, 2 and 3 appear to be the most reliable on the devices my colleague tested.  Here is his full analysis:

[image: user device name table of results]

Source: https://medium.com/@pribble88/how-to-get-an-android-device-nickname-4b4700b3068c

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these methods work on Pixel 2 XL emulator (api 28). They all return null!

Answer (score 13):

```
BluetoothAdapter myDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
String deviceName = myDevice.getName();
```

returns Galaxy S5.

```
String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;
returns SM-G900H.
```

After some research I found the device_name in /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db

so, to get it using shell command

```
shell@k3g:/ $ settings get system device_name
settings get system device_name
Milky Way
```

using java

```
String deviceName = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), "device_name");
returns Milky Way
```

POC github project
https://github.com/kakopappa/getdevcicename

detailed explanation:
http://androidbridge.blogspot.com/2016/09/how-to-get-android-device-name-settings.html

Comment: this was returning a null :(

Comment: This returns what the user named his device in settings: `settings get global device_name` and in java `Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(), "device_name");`

Comment: That shell command returns "null" on Android P (Pixel) despite having set the value in the Settings section of the phone.

Comment: The `Settings.System` method now returns "null" as well.

Comment: thanks for providing this answer interpreting the question as being about the device's user-assigned name, not the device's model name.  as others have mentioned, none of the methods here seem to be working with my kindle (android 5.1.1).  They return variously `null`, `Fire`, or `KFDOWI`.  hm.  [android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#DEVICE_NAME) say that device_name was added in API level 25, which apparently means Fire OS 6, so i guess this makes sense. sort of. why is `settings get global device_name` returning anything at all then ?

Answer (score 6):

This one worked for me on API 25:

```
Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_name");
```

Here's how to find it... (just replace the name of your device)

```
$ adb shell
$ settings list system | grep "<device_name>"
$ settings list secure | grep "<device_name>"
```

Comment: In my version of ADB (1.0.36) in macOS, the settings command does not have a `list` option, just `get` and `put`.

Comment: Correction: The `settings` shell command on my cheap LG tracfone does not have the `list` option.

Comment: Just to add another variant, my Samsung J2 has the device name in global settings. `settings list global | grep "<device_name>"`

Comment: Just want to add that on an Android 13 (api level 33) device, this now triggers a `SecurityException` in Release builds saying "Settings key: <bluetooth_name> is only readable to apps with targetSdkVersion lower than or equal to: 31". targetSdkVersion set to 33, worked w/ 31.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;
```

Comment: Thanks articles, but that only gives me the phone (SAMSUNG-SGH-I337) name not the one I set in Settings->about device->Device Name.

Comment: So far I've tried: System.getProperty("net.hostname"); and android.os.Build.MODEL;

Comment: Dont expect Samsung to follow the same standards set by Google. Its possible they may do things their own way.

Comment: This was the same on another device (non samsung) this just gave me the actual Model and not user defined Device Name.

Comment: Note that even having a "Settings->About->DeviceName" is a vendor customization, rather than a part of Android itself.

Comment: It's settings → bluetooth → option menu → rename phone on stock android.

Answer (score 2):

No of the above mentioned methods work for all devices. If you want a robust way to get *user defined device name* on almost all Android devices (including TV) and not requiring any permissions use this

```
String userDeviceName = Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVICE_NAME);
if(userDeviceName == null)
    userDeviceName = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line worked for me:

`String userDeviceName = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_name");`

However, I had to ensure that -

- The app is running on devices with API level 25 or higher
- **Bluetooth** was **turned on** at least once after updating the device name. Otherwise, the `getString()` will only return the **old device name**.