# How to get device name defined by user with android 4.4

Tags: android

I have an apk which get the device name defined by the user.

For that I use this code (see at [How do you get the user defined “Device Name” in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704597/how-do-you-get-the-user-defined-device-name-in-android/22911592#22911592)):

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter =  BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();     
TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
txtName.setText(mBluetoothAdapter.getName());
```

It works well on a android 4.1 / Samsung Galaxy tab3. Unfortunately when I test it on android 4.4 Samsung Galaxy tab pro, it doesn't work. On the new device I get the same result like `android.os.Build.MODEL`

If someone have an idea.

Thanks

Comment: you have to tried with serial name on tab.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,I already tried each properties of `android.os.Build` like SERIAL, HOST, BOARD, DEVICE, ... but i didn't get the _famous_ device name defined by user.

Comment: if you not get by device name then you have to tried with device serial.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but if i tried `android.os.Build.SERIAL` I get _3204117122fcb003_, that doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get it from `Settings.Secure`:

```
Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_name");
```