# How to fetch Device Name (NOT Build.MODEL) from Android programatically?

Tags: android, device, application-settings

I have been searching for code through which I can fetch Device's name defined by user for his own device .
Have gone through various stackoverflow questions , but none seems to work for me ?

Image as seen in below : Will require Thanks Thanks (SM-T211 ) from android code

[image]

Comment: which one ?? can you elaborate by example ??

Comment: where does the user define device name?

Comment: AFAIK i dont see any user editable control in settings > about. can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Please check image added

Comment: @Yatin try the below answer that I gave.

Comment: AFAIK thats device / manufacturer specific. I dont have that feature in my device (Asus Zenfone 2)

Comment: if the "Thanks Thanks" name shows up as bluetooth device name in your other devices, you can use the bluetooth answer, if not you have to use the build.prop answer

Comment: From bluetooth I do get it but ,its the other device's name which I am pairing with device.getName() property from bluetooth adapter . How to get my own device name ... is the question

Comment: So , from below answers I assume that to get answer , I will have to root the device , else I wont be able to retrieve Device name from my own device .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the user defined "Device Name" in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704597/how-do-you-get-the-user-defined-device-name-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String ownerInfo = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
    "lock_screen_owner_info");
```

As of Android 4.4.2 the owner info value is moved to lock screen `database,/data/system/locksettings.db` to which 3rd-party apps have no `read/write access`. That's, there is no reliable way of reading owner info for later Android versions except for rooted device.

Comment: FYI, you can find a more detailed answer listing all the options here: https://medium.com/@pribble88/how-to-get-an-android-device-nickname-4b4700b3068c

Answer (score 1):

You need to get build.prop file of system which is possible either if your device is rooted or if your has system privileges....
heres the code you may follow to get and edit build.prop
Check this App in Play Store. build.prop Editor. Since it's open source, and the code is extremely simple, you can use it as a stating point: **https://github.com/nathanpc/Build.prop-Editor**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
BluetoothAdapter myDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
String deviceName = myDevice.getName();
```

Make sure you add to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

Comment: I know this ... this one gives only model name

Comment: I need to know the user defined name as seen in About Device

Comment: So , from below answers I assume that to get answer , I will have to root the device , else I wont be able to retrieve Device name from my own device .