# How to get device name from phone settings in android

Tags: android

How to read the device name from phone setting in android, As shown in below image how to read the first field that is "device name" in android.

In some phones, the device name is the same as the model name but in some phones both are different so how to particular read device name from phone settings in[image] android?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As i know you can not do that in android versions after oreo

Comment: Any were documented please provide the link?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes - here go to  Restriction on non-resettable device identifiers

Answer (score 5):

here you go

```
Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVICE_NAME)
```

Comment: Phone state permission is required?

Comment: Requires API N_MRI Annoation

Comment: yes, this will work on API  level 25 and above

Comment: project which i m developing is 23 and above

Comment: below api level 25, check out these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704597/how-do-you-get-the-user-defined-device-name-in-android/41877366

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use this, Use in your logcat to see the result.

```
Build.DEVICE
```

Comment: What you actually want can you specify.

Comment: As mentioned above and shwon in image need to get device name from device setting->about