# How to find the Android device name

Tags: android

Suppose I am using some device to run the android program but now I wanted to know the device name which I m using through code.How can I get it.

Comment: 5 seconds of Googling found my this [See here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071281/get-android-device-name

Comment: sorry 2 say i have usd this but I m not getting the correct result

Answer (score 2):

```
   public static String getDeviceName() {
    String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String model = Build.MODEL;
    if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
        return capitalize(model);
    } else {
        return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
    }
}


  private static String capitalize(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    char first = s.charAt(0);
    if (Character.isUpperCase(first)) {
        return s;
    } else {
        return Character.toUpperCase(first) + s.substring(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is capitalize method here..

Comment: just for set latters in uppercase

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to get the Device name:-

```
String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;
System.out.println("Device Name--"+deviceName);
```