# Android to get Device Name like( s2,s3 ) programmatically

Tags: android

In Android can we get Device Name like( s2,s3 ) programmatically. I donot want to get Model number because it varies for same device.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071281 ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you indeed can: `String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;`

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build

Comment: It Provides the Model Number of the Device like GT-19100.But i want to get name like s2,s3

Comment: Hmm, what about `Build.PRDUCT`?

Comment: It provides the same info as android.os.Build.MODEL.

Comment: Bad luck :( Let's see if anyone knows a solution then. Otherwise you might have to end up mapping models to human-friendly models

Answer (score 0):

You can get device information from this

`Model: Build.MODEL` The end-user-visible name for the end product.

`Manufacturer: Build.MANUFACTURER` The name of the industrial design.

`Board: Build.BOARD` The name of the underlying board, like "goldfish".

`Brand: Build.BRAND` The consumer-visible brand with which the product/hardware will be associated, if any.

`Serial: Build.SERIAL` The serial number you can get.

it's all information of the device you can get.