# How to get devicename in Android (Samsung device)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to get the name of my device (Samsung SM-P900) not the model name.

If i try to get the name with code like this:

```
    BluetoothAdapter myDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    String deviceName = myDevice.getName();     
    return deviceName;
```

it gives me a Model name like SM-P900, but it is not that what i want.

Have any idea???

**EDIT:** 
[Here is wat i want.](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=69c23ff4c5255036!29120&authkey=!ACZzi69LS4gcd8c&v=3&ithint=photo%2CPNG)

Answer (score 2):

To display the device name/model in android use:

```
TextView myTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTv);
String name = android.os.Build.MODEL;
myTv.setText(name);
```

Please refer to this link as well: [Android build class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)

Comment: Thanks. But its not work for mee. Samsung have a editable Device name (like My Samsung) and i need to get this name not the name of Build.Model.

Comment: Alright, did you make sure that you added this permission to your manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>  ?

Comment: Yes. it returns me SM-P900. :-( I want to get that here: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=69c23ff4c5255036!29120&authkey=!ACZzi69LS4gcd8c&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG

Comment: I found this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7071281/2268466 , it may help you !

Comment: The device name property is not implemented in core Android - it is something that device manufacturers may add on their own.  There is no general way to retrieve this property.