# How can my app show different icons when on Huawei or honor

Tags: android, icons

I want my android app to have different launcher icons when on different devices. Specifically, on Huawei and honor, one icon, and all other devices another.
Is it possible ?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no way to specify different icons based on which specific phone model your app is installed on.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071281/get-android-device-name). It's a single way. Or just ask the user about it =).

Comment: You can refer to this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995439/get-android-phone-model-programmatically

Comment: thank you for replay :) and thank you for links !)))