# Google Play Console Exclude devices

Tags: android, google-play

I'm in trouble with publishing android application on google play console, the problem is that my app must be available only for one brand of devices, but it's compatible with 10208 devices and google play brings them all, and there's no way to exclude them all and then activate only the brand I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: "and there's no way to exclude them all and then activate only the brand I want" you answered your question yourself or not?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html can't see a device filter in there

Comment: no there's no filter for that.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't that problem on my own but if you're saying there's no way to limit devices on Google Play you can try to do that at runtime.

If you're sure about only one particular device you can see its `android.os.Build.MODEL`, `android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER` and `android.os.Build.PRODUCT`. Then just check these values against running device if they match your hardcoded values. If it doesn't match close the app or do whatever you like.

[Get Android Device Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071281/get-android-device-name)

Comment: It's a way, but it will be better that app won't be visible to excluded devices, the only way I found is to manually exclude each device :) it's like to do more than 10000 clicks, a waste of time and energy.

Comment: There's no better way. I saw a few apps which show a nice dialog after app started like "Sorry, your device is not supported" :)

Answer (score 0):

Android is designed to be an open ecosystem, with many manufacturers. As an App developer who doesn't work for a device manufacturer you normally shouldn't be developing for a single brand, but instead for the whole ecosystem of compatible devices.

Having said this, device manufacturers often want their software to just run on their devices. The way they normally do this is use a custom [uses-feature element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) which only exists on their devices. If you work for a manufacturer they may be able to add one to the OS rom for you, or already have one. Or if you have a given device you may be able to use an app like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.odk.collect.android.doform to display its features, and spot the one you want. This is not normally recommended unless you work for a manufacturer.

Be aware, anyone with a custom ROM can work round this. So it is not a security feature, just a convenience feature for the user so they don't get an app which doesn't work.