# What is changed with Bluetooth in Android SDK 32?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

After changing my `targetSdk` to 32, I get the following error:

```
Settings key: <bluetooth_address> is only readable to apps with targetSdkVersion lower than or equal to: 31
```

I think this is happening while checking permissions while loading my app.

Comment: Does your app include any third party libraries especially for tracking/showing ads?

Comment: Yes, it does. The library causing the issue is the Zebra Scanner SDK.

Comment: @Sean did you figure out what the solution was ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've reverted to targetSdk 31 and I'm waiting for an update to the Zebra scanner SDK to switch to 32. I've seen some things now require a target sdk of 32. Worst case, I'll drop support for the barcode scanner until they update it or I find a workaround.

Comment: did you find a workaround for this? i am getting the same issue with bluetooth_name

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I switched back to 31. I'm waiting for an update for the library causing the issue.

Comment: I have same problem but don't have Zebra Scanner SDK. My compileSdkVersion/targetSdk is 33

Comment: But it looks like OneSignal has the same problem: https://github.com/OneSignal/onesignal-expo-plugin/issues/107

Comment: Zebra has released a new scanner SDK version that fixes this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Issue is due to few parameters are annotated with **maxTargetSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.S**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3aaX.png)

For **bluetooth_name** I found the alternative and reading **device_name** using below code:

```
Settings.Global.getString(application.contentResolver, Settings.Global.DEVICE_NAME)
        ?: "UNKNOWN"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for me by downgrading the gradle version to 7.0.4 and setting both the compileSdkVersion and the targetSdkVersion to 31.

Unfortunately it's not the fix that i wanted but this is an intermediate step for now to continue working

Comment: You shouldn't need to downgrade gradle. I assume you actually mean the Android Gradle Plugin. Just lowering your target SDK version should work. Do you know what library is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change Target version directly. Before doing so see android documentation on migrating your application to specific target version.
Failing to do so will result in errors, as the changes each android SDK has its own features and upgrades which are not compatible with old code. Just by changing Target SDK version back you can solve this error. However, could most like to be or soon to be deprecated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).