# Settings key: <bluetooth_address> is only readable to apps with targetSdkVersion lower than or equal: 31

Tags: xamarin.android, bluetooth, android-api-levels, android-13, zebra-scanners

I have an application in Xamarin.Android which has an API level 33/Android 13, the app integrates with Zebra scanners and in this case I am trying to connect a Zebra DS3678 to my application. In previous versions (API Level < 31 / Android 12) The scanner connects perfectly but now I have the error that is in the title of the question.

Working with API Levels, I always notice that they touch and modify all Bluetooth issues but I couldn't find what should change for API Level 32 or higher (33 in my case)

I contacted the Zebra team but I had no answers (because I think a posible solution is upgrade the Zebra SDK Hander) and I can't downgrade either because it is a corporate app

This is my bluetooth configuration

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<!-- FOR 30 AND BELOW -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<!-- for 31 and above -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SOCIAL_STREAM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: You can try the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this case that has the similar error message as yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271363/what-is-changed-with-bluetooth-in-android-sdk-32), this is an issue in the old Zebra SDK, and it was fixed in the newest release version.

So you can try to download [the newest Zebra SDK for Xamarin](https://www.zebra.com/apps/dlmanager?dlp=7b8a235653193b4c72c440110c25661656f56f5180957c98e7c0bc2144149cd156a1bc6e684725ab35632bcef45681743f9de60a9e47f4c4b0b525f576635cd6cdc63715540470fa9a5a49725420d5e98f0ffac8b111bab0d65661a96d4289b6aff9a84520f3b40e78763dfc6daad4173c060997cce3d0af&c=us&l=en) from [the official website](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/zebra-rfid-xamarin-sdk-and-demoapp-for-android.html).